# Best way to create a loop for multiplying a matrix by every one of its elements, then summing the results

Tags: python, performance, coding-efficiency

very new to Python so apologies for the lack of vocabulary/knowledge. I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve what the code below provides. Using the loop I have made, I can generate and append all of the matrices/arrays formed from multiplying matrix A by each and every element within A. The last line of code then sums all of the elements in this array of arrays and prints out the result I want.

The problem is, when I get to about d = 600, I get SIGKILL errors, due to a lack of memory on my computer.

I have considered the mathematics behind it, which included breaking the summation into parts that dealt with different values of indices, but nothing seems to speed it up significantly.

This may be purely a memory-based issue, but I thought I would ask in case there are any Python/code based tips that could help. The code is as follows:

```
A = numpy.random.randint(0, 4, size=(d, d))

All = []
for n in range(0, d):
    for m in range(0, d):
        All.append(A*(A[n,m]))

print(numpy.sum(All))
```

So overall, I achieve the correct result, but due to the large size of the matrices and the number of multiplications, I cannot achieve the required d = 2000 I am looking for without a memory error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do looping here and building a new list if all you want is the total sum... what you're doing mathematically comes down to:

```
total = A.sum() ** 2
```

Comment: Wow, talk about me overcomplicating things. Thanks alot Jon, of course that is exactly what I was after.